# Keyboard shortcut for switching between buttons in a dialog

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I was wondering if there is a way, like using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, to switch with the keyboard between buttons on a dialog box, where a program asks for a decision? *(Example below)*

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> is supposed to work (and does), but Yosemite seems to have a bug in regard to highlighting which button is selected. The entire button being blue means the button is the default, but there should also be a visual indicator of which button is selected.

You can test that <kbd>Tab</kbd> does in fact work. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the page you are looking at right now. Then, in the Save sheet, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, and press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. The Save sheet will disappear because you selected the Cancel button and executed it (with the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>).

Because of the lack of a visual indicator, unfortunately this is going to be difficult to use until the visual bug is fixed.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the visual indicator in Yosemite, it works just fine for me. However, as detailed here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38015/how-can-i-switch-dialog-buttons-using-the-keyboard?rq=1 there is a setting that must be enabled to use the tab key to move between buttons.