# Navigating OS X dialogs with the keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, dialog

I am a keyboardist and using the mouse is slow and distracting. For the following dialog - which is just an example since there are others similar to it - how would one choose a non-default button using the keyboard?

[image]

I have tried arrow keys, tab, various letters .. none do anything to move the selected button.

Does Apple dislike keyboardists?

Comment: The answer in  [How can I switch dialog buttons using the keyboard](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38015/how-can-i-switch-dialog-buttons-using-the-keyboard) seems to perfectly fit your problem.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Yes, I realize now that the link you provide perfectly answers javadba's question. The question you link to applies to OS X 10.7 "Lion", though, good to know OS X 10.10 "Yosemite" can be configured the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.10 "Yosemite" (and older versions at least back to OS X 10.7 "Lion") lets you use the Tab key to navigate between buttons (and other items) on the screen. To configure it select "All controls" in System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts as shown below:

[image]

When the desired button has focus, press the Space bar to select it. (Don't press Enter, as it will select the default button.)