# Move focus between buttons in confirm dialogs OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, keyboard

When I try to export a file with the same name (in InDesign CS6) I get a popup asking if I want to replace the file.

[image]

**How can I move focus between the `Cancel` and `Replace` buttons using only the keyboard?**

I have found that if I press this sequence <kbd>Tab</kbd> > <kbd>Tab</kbd> > <kbd>Space</kbd> the `replace` button is pressed instead of `cancel`, but I get no visual indication this will happen. Is this a bug?

Comment: Don't you see a surround to the button as per http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38017/237

Comment: @Mark no nothing

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to allow the Mac to move focus between dialog boxes.

One is by going into `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and clicking the `All Controls` Radio button on the bottom.

[image]

Another way to do is is by hitting `Fn`+`⌃`+`F7` to toggle between `All Controls` and `Text boxes and lists only` (`^`+`F7` if you haven't switched the apple media keys to `Fn` keys).

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the spacebar.

(It's not necessary to use tab if the button you desire pressed is already outlined.)

This also works with highlighted checkboxes.